# Java apps opening in wrong version of Java

Tags: windows, java

I have installed Java 8 on Windows 7 using the STATIC=1 switch, expecting the install to leave my path value alone to retain my Java 7 install as the default. This didn't work, and the path value was amended by adding C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath at the beginning of the path. I have removed this from path, but applications are still opening using Java8 as default I have even replaced the shortcuts in the above directories with shortcuts that go to Java7, but that hasn't worked. I have also put the path to Java7 at the beginning of my Path environmental variable.

What am I doing wrong? Why are my applications still using Java8 and not Java7?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've found that it'll run from java7 via the command line and via 8 when going to the URL for the jnlp through IE. Not sure why.

Comment: Due to the infamous vulnerabilities of java running a non latest version on a machine that connects to the internet is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm aware of the risks, but we have a business critical application that requires an out dated version unfortunately. It's not something I can do anything about. The thing is, we also require a newer application to run the latest version and I am trying to get them running side by side, which should be entirely possible.

Comment: There's a post over on StackOverflow that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551668/how-do-i-set-the-default-java-installation-runtime-windows

Comment: I have seen that article already and unfortunately I have tried creating a java home environmental variable and it didn't make any difference. This is one of the reasons why I am stuck, as the Path variable should provide a link to the javaw.exe application for Java 8 in order for the apt o use it to launch, but it doesn't. I appreciate the effort to provide the link though.

Comment: @Linef4ult: Java isn't more **insecure** than all other apps created with C/C++/Delphi/VB! When it comes to security in Java, **ONLY** the java-sandbox (e.g Browser-Plugin) is affected, not Java itself.

Comment: Of course the language isn't insecure, but the implementation of it in use is the source of constant security patches and running any vulnerable code in a web facing environment is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being unexpected behaviour when launching the jnlp via the url. If I try to run `javaws "<Place JNLP URL here>"` it runs in java 7 as expected. Navigating to it via IE launches it in Java 8. It's very odd but I guess it's a setting server side.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that Java also places the java.exe/javaw.exe into **system32** dir
(which is also on Path-Variable), when installing Java?
This **may** be a problem.
Try to remove it from **system32** or **replace** it (java.exe/javaw.exe) with your needed Version.
Further 1: You can de-/activate Java-Versions in Java Control-Panel.
Further 2: The JNLP can specify it's needed Java-Version which is required to run the application (check the JNLP for **<j2se version="1.8+" >**).

**PS:** (cause of some comments)
Java **is not** more insecure than all other apps created with C/C++/Delphi/VB! 
When it comes to securtity, in almost all cases the **java-sandbox** is meant.

Cheers!